# Why when I throw SqlException using Mockito with some parameters It is not recognized?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, sqlexception

I have Dao method that throws several exception depending on Sql error code.All of them will go to the Service layer.

```
public boolean insertUser(Connection connection, User user) throws MySQLEXContainer.MySQLDBNotUniqueException, MySQLEXContainer.MySQLDBLargeDataException, MySQLEXContainer.MySQLDBExecutionException, SQLException {
        int rowNum = 0;
        ResultSet keys = null;
        Connection con;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        try {
            String query = QueriesUtil.getQuery("insertUser");
            con = connection;
            statement = con.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            statement.setString(1, user.getLogin());
            statement.setString(2, PasswordUtil.generateStrongPasswordHash(user.getPassword()));
            statement.setString(3, user.getUserType());
            statement.setString(4, user.getUserEmail());
            rowNum = statement.executeUpdate();
            keys = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
            if (keys.next()) {
                user.setUserId(keys.getInt(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
            if (e.getErrorCode() == 1062) {
                throw new MySQLEXContainer.MySQLDBNotUniqueException(String.format("Your login : %s or Email %s already exists", user.getLogin(), user.getUserEmail()), e.getCause());
            } else if (e.getErrorCode() == 1406) {
                throw new MySQLEXContainer.MySQLDBLargeDataException("Data Is too long", e);
            }
            throw new MySQLEXContainer.MySQLDBExecutionException("Bad execution", e);
        } finally {
            ConnectionUtil.oneMethodToCloseThemAll(keys, statement, null);
        }
        return rowNum > 0;
    }
```

At the Service layer I catch them and throw other exceptions depending on throwed exceptions in Dao Layer.

Service layer

```
public boolean insertUser(User user) throws ApplicationEXContainer.ApplicationCanNotChangeException, ApplicationEXContainer.ApplicationCanChangeException {
        boolean result=false;
        try(Connection connection = MySQLDAOFactory.getConnection();
            AutoRollback autoRollback = new AutoRollback(connection)){
            result =  userDao.insertUser(connection,user);
            autoRollback.commit();
        } catch (SQLException | NamingException | MySQLEXContainer.MySQLDBExecutionException throwables) {
            throw new ApplicationEXContainer.ApplicationCanNotChangeException(throwables);
        } catch (MySQLEXContainer.MySQLDBLargeDataException | MySQLEXContainer.MySQLDBNotUniqueException mySQLDBExceptionCanChange) {
            throw new ApplicationEXContainer.ApplicationCanChangeException(mySQLDBExceptionCanChange.getMessage(),mySQLDBExceptionCanChange);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

In Test class I have this method for checking exception

```
@Test
    void insertUserNotUniqueException() throws SQLException, MySQLEXContainer.MySQLDBExecutionException, MySQLEXContainer.MySQLDBLargeDataException, MySQLEXContainer.MySQLDBNotUniqueException, ApplicationEXContainer.ApplicationCanNotChangeException, ApplicationEXContainer.ApplicationCanChangeException {
        User user = new User();
        when(userDao.insertUser(any(Connection.class),any(User.class))).thenThrow(new SQLException("Login or Email is already in database","23000",1062));
        Throwable thrown = assertThrows(ApplicationEXContainer.ApplicationCanChangeException.class,()->taxiServiceUser.insertUser(user));
        assertEquals("Login or Email is already in database",thrown.getMessage());
    }
```

In webapp it all works fine, but when I use Mockito I get this StackTrace

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception type thrown ==> expected: <com.example.FinalProjectPM.db.exception.ApplicationEXContainer.ApplicationCanChangeException> but was: <com.example.FinalProjectPM.db.exception.ApplicationEXContainer.ApplicationCanNotChangeException>

    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:65)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows(Assertions.java:3007)
    at com.example.FinalProjectPM.db.services.TaxiServiceUserTest.insertUserNotUniqueException(TaxiServiceUserTest.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: com.example.FinalProjectPM.db.exception.ApplicationEXContainer$ApplicationCanNotChangeException: java.sql.SQLException: Login or Email is already in database
    at com.example.FinalProjectPM.db.services.TaxiServiceUser.insertUser(TaxiServiceUser.java:28)
    at com.example.FinalProjectPM.db.services.TaxiServiceUserTest.lambda$insertUserNotUniqueException$0(TaxiServiceUserTest.java:53)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:55)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Login or Email is already in database
    at com.example.FinalProjectPM.db.services.TaxiServiceUser.insertUser(TaxiServiceUser.java:25)
    ... 70 more
```

So User Dao insert method throw wrong exception.
Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply made a mistake: highlighted the points of interests in the code copied below

```java
public boolean insertUser(User user) throws ApplicationEXContainer.ApplicationCanNotChangeException, ApplicationEXContainer.ApplicationCanChangeException {
        boolean result=false;
        try(Connection connection = MySQLDAOFactory.getConnection();
            AutoRollback autoRollback = new AutoRollback(connection)){
            result =  userDao.insertUser(connection,user); // here it throws an SQLException
            autoRollback.commit();
        } catch (SQLException | NamingException | MySQLEXContainer.MySQLDBExecutionException throwables) {
// here it catches and throws exactly the exception the test says was thrown
            throw new ApplicationEXContainer.ApplicationCanNotChangeException(throwables); 
        } catch (MySQLEXContainer.MySQLDBLargeDataException | MySQLEXContainer.MySQLDBNotUniqueException mySQLDBExceptionCanChange) {
            throw new ApplicationEXContainer.ApplicationCanChangeException(mySQLDBExceptionCanChange.getMessage(),mySQLDBExceptionCanChange);
        }
        return result;
  }
```